# Empty result: Laravel/PostgreSQL where Json array column contains one of these items

Tags: laravel, postgresql

In my `Food` model i have a column named `countries` which is a json field.

I have collected asian countries in one array and my plans is to get the records if the `countries` column has *one of* the country in the array, I did the below:

```php
$asian = [
    "South Korea",
    "Pakistan",
    "Afghanistan",
    .
    .
    .
];

Food::whereJsonContains('countries', $asian)->get();
```

It returns empty collection, It seems like it looking for a record that contais all of the countries but i'm looking for a way to tell match records if "one of the countries" matched not all of them at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I had the same issue with laravel 8. It returns empty array even though it's documented to be used like this:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereJsonContains('options->languages', ['en', 'de'])
    ->get();
```

You can solve this issue like this:

```
Food::where(function ($query) use ($asian) {
    foreach ($asian as $country) {
        $query->orWhereJsonContains('countries', $country);
    }
})->get();
```

and don't forget to add `countries` field into `$cast` variable in your model. This will instruct Eloquent to deserialize it from JSON into a PHP array:

```
class Food extends Model 
{
    ...
   protected $casts = [
        'countries' => 'array'
    ];
    ...
}
```

### Update

Although the above code solves the issue, I found that the `whereJsonContains` method works fine. I was inserting the data in a wrong way and I didn't get any error on that! Make sure you are inserting the data in a proper way as you wouldn't get an error if you try to insert to JSON data like this:

```
Food::factory()->create([
    'countries' => 'USA'
]);
```

I tested this on Laravel 8, IDK if this happens on older versions.

Your data should be like this:

```
{

    {
        ...
        'countries': ['USA', 'China']
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case this:

```
Food::whereJsonContains('countries', $asian)->get();
```

It would return `Food`s that their `countries` contained within `$array`.